# %velo interpreter is missing from Zeppling

Tags: apache-zeppelin, vora

I have setup the vora, after installing and setup everything running fine but the interpreter %velo in Zeppline account is missing I have other interprer like %spark , %pyspark , %sql , %dep , %vora,
but %velo is missing, how do I get it.

Thanks,Prem

Answer (score 0):

The interpreter prefix `%velo` was used in older versions and is deprecated. The correct name for the SAP HANA Vora interpreter prefix in Zeppelin is `%vora`.